# seeing sales data by "WEEK' in power bi

Tags: powerbi

Can you help me figure out how to display sales data by "WEEKS" in power BI visuals ? I have a calendar table and the date hierarchy is listed by Year, Quarter, Month and Day with no week option.[the visual I'd like to create is the chart at the bottom of the image I have attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGcGs.png) Thanks

Comment: You should blank out or remove items with your company and products in examples. You have displayed company confidential information, margins etc, if this is real data.

Comment: @Jon, thanks for the heads up but it's not real data (It's a template provided to me for the assignment I was working on while I was taking some classes on power bi)..I appreciate all your help since i am just a fresher learning the trades and tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in the Week to your calendar.
If your are using DAX there are a number of ways
To show the week number of the year use [WEEKNUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/weeknum-function-dax)

```
Week No = WEEKNUM(Table1[Date], 2)
```

[image: Power BI Table showing week number]

For the start of the week in a date format use

```
Start of Week = 'Calendar'[Date]  - WEEKDAY('Calendar'[Date],2) +1
```

The equivalent functions in Power Query are [Date.WeekOfYear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-weekofyear) and [Date.StartOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-startofweek)

[image: Power Query Week Functions]